# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index using jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I'm a newbie JAVA. I have a config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.docs.test" />
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.217:1521:ksoradev"/>
        <property name="username" value="pkrdm"/>
        <property name="password" value="mypass"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and then my code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.config.xml");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.getBean("dataSource");
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String lastName = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "select a.firstname from TEST a",
                new Object[]{1212L}, String.class);
         System.out.println(lastName);
    }
}
```

When i run it, it return error Invalid column index. Can anyone help me ?

Thank

Comment: its missing a where clause. select a.firstname from Test a where <columnname> = ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [queryForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Class)) , which expects an array of objects to bind to a `PreparedStatement` type query with placeholders.

Your query is probably missing placeholders, e.g :

```
select a.firstname from TEST a where id = ?
```

You get errors about invalid column indexes, because the content of your array cannot currently be mapped to any placeholders indexes.